# django project on Ubuntu running nginx unable to upload files

Tags: python, django, nginx, cloudinary, ubuntu-22.04

I keep getting this error while trying to upload a file via the django admin

```
2023/08/24 10:51:09 [warn] 4147#4147: *1 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000001, client: 172.71.98.67, server: 72.167.132.218, request: "POST /ran-admin/blog/post/add/ HTTP/1.1", host: "redaid-nigeria.org", referrer: "https://redaid-nigeria.org/ran-admin/blog/post/add/"
2023/08/24 10:52:02 [error] 4147#4147: *10 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2023/08/24 10:52:02 [error] 4147#4147: *11 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx_status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2023/08/24 10:53:28 [warn] 4147#4147: *18 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000002, client: 172.71.98.159, server: 72.167.132.218, request: "POST /ran-admin/blog/post/add/ HTTP/1.1", host: "redaid-nigeria.org", referrer: "https://redaid-nigeria.org/ran-admin/blog/post/add/"
2023/08/24 10:58:06 [warn] 4147#4147: *25 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000003, client: 172.70.46.67, server: 72.167.132.218, request: "POST /ran-admin/blog/post/add/ HTTP/1.1", host: "redaid-nigeria.org", referrer: "https://redaid-nigeria.org/ran-admin/blog/post/add/"
```

Initially I could upload smaller files and only got this error for large files (> 1MB). Now, the error shows for even files as small as 2KB. Please advice

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/domainwww .conf file is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 72.167.132.218 redaid-nigeria.org www.redaid-nigeria.org;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ranvps/ranwww;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

My nginx.conf is

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I have tried all of these options in my sites-available/domainwww and even in my nginx.conf

```
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
client_body_buffer_size     10M;
client_max_body_size 10M;
proxy_buffering                 off;
```

Comment: `client request body is buffered to a temporary file` is just a warning. Should not prevent file uploads. I would be more worried about the `[error]` messages in that snippet. It looks like Nginx can't find a route and falling back to a default, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I thought so too but that warning triggers a 500 error page

Comment: What does the 500 error page tell you? Is this a 500 error page from Nginx or Django? Also the host in the `error` logs is different, which could signal some clashing configuration.

Comment: Fixed it! Apparently, I made a change in the models that was not properly migrated to the database. hence the 500 error. It's a Django error! Crazy how I didn't think that. Thanks @OnikuteOpeyemiO